# How to pipe bash script output to a file on windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, windows-scripting

I am running on Windows 7.

I have a bash script which runs fine from a Windows command prompt using `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" "C:\path\myBashScript.sh" 17.1`. I can see it running in a new bash window, the output looks fine and it closes. What I want to do is capture the output in a file for further processing.

I tried

`"C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" "C:\path\myBashScript.sh" 17.1 > C:\out\myBashScript.out.txt`

but all I get in the output is the working folder, ie, 
`C:\path>`

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Probably STDERR output? try `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" "C:\path\myBashScript.sh" 17.1 > C:\out\myBashScript.out.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @Ben. That didn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

"C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" is a frontend windows launcher. I'm surprised it takes any argument at all. You should run bash scripts using bash interpreter:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" "C:\path\myBashScript.sh"
```

PS: I'd advise to apply redirection inside the bash script rather than in windows commandline, they are better controlled there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to discriminate between the outputs generated within the shell script, and those generated by the command line execution.

To easily capture the output of the shell script, you may find it easier to do the redirection > to the capture file within the script.

You didn't say what style of system you were on, and how it was set up (Cygwin, GfW; command line in cmd.exe, or bash; integrated or separated git commands (in the cmd.exe), etc). I suspect that the inability to do a simple redirection of the command line is because of that system setup issue.

Comment: I am using git-cmd.exe which is installed as part of GitForWindows. I am running it from the Windows Cmd Prompt, although this is a test bed for TeamCity's CommandLine runner, as this will form part of the build process. I get the same results in both environments, although I think that is because TeamCity uses the host's command line environment. Having read that, is there anything you can suggest?

Comment: @Badgerspot my suggestion would be to move the redirection inside the quoted bash command. e.g. (completely untried;-) `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" "C:\path\myBashScript.sh 17.1 > C:\out\myBashScript.out.txt"`